# Negative TIME values in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-manager, mysql-manager

I was using MySQL with phpMyAdmin to manage a small database and system that my company was using to store the time a employee starts and finishes his shift.

If say employee works 8 hours a day but starts at "08:00" and finishes at "15:00", for example, it stores "-01:00", if he finishes at "17:00", it would store "01:00".

That's not the best way to mess with time, I get it, but for the moment we have to deal with this...

It's all doing fine, except I decided to open the MySQL database with SQL Manager 2010 instead of phpMyAdmin. This editor doesn't let a TIME be stored as negative as in phpMyAdmin, and it messed up the entire table just by opening it...

Is there a way to enable negative time values in MySQL?

Comment: There is no such thing as a negative time value.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html ?

Comment: Yes, but that is not what you're describing.

Comment: Could you tell us what  the column was configured for? INT? DATE? TIME?

Comment: It's TIME. @JayBlanchard I know it's not the best way to deal with time, as I said. But until I fix this made "system" we'll have to deal with this...I just don't get why I can store "negative" TIME in phpMyAdmin but can't in SQL Manager 2010